# Angular user JSON request from a static file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I am currently trying to implement this AngularJS example [Tutorial Example Login](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/angularjs-basic-http-authentication-example) but instead of having the username and password stored as **strings**, I am trying to extract the from a local file.

*I know that this is a bad practice but that is how I am trying to do it.*

In the section `AngularJS Authentication Service. Path: /modules/authentication/services.js` in the example, the username and password are stored in a timeout function as:

```
$timeout(function(){
var response = { success: username === 'test' && password === 'test' };
  if(!response.success) {
      response.message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
     }
       callback(response);
}, 1000);
```

but I am trying to create a static **json** file which holders the username and password as objects. My idea was to make a `$http.get` request to the file and append the json objects to the username and password parameters like this:

```
var details;
$http.get("data.json").then(function(response){
$scope.details = response.data;
    console.log(username);
});


$timeout(function () {
var response = { success: username === details.username && password === details.password 
if (!response.success) {
   response.message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
}
 callback(response);
}, 1000);
```

but I am getting two errors :
1.`ReferenceError: $scope is not defined`
2.`TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`

> What is the esiest way to achieve what I am trying to do? Extract the
>   username and password from a json file and not have them as a static
>   string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some snippets are from http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/angularjs-basic-http-authentication-example

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/WvOwk1?p=preview

#### What did I change?

The original login snippet is:

```
service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {
    $timeout(function(){
        var response = { success: username === 'test' && password === 'test' };
        if(!response.success) {
            response.message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
        }
        callback(response);
    }, 1000);
};
```

I changed it to:

```
var promise = $http.get("data.json").then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
});

service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {
    promise.then(function (data) {
        var success = data.some(function (user) {
            if (user.username == username && user.password == password) {
                callback({
                    success: true
                });
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (!success) {
            callback({
                success: false,
                message: 'Username or password is incorrect'
            });
        }
    });
};
```

And added a data.json:

```
[{
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test"
}, {
    "username": "test2",
    "password": "test2"
}]
```

#### Why promise?

Since you use json file as db, you should load the json file with network. And you don't need to load the data.json since it doesn't change, so you can just load it once. Using `promise.then` to ensure the verification is after the `$http.get`.

If you want to load the "data.json" each time the user submits the form, just replace `promise.then` with

```
$http.get("data.json").then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
}).then
```

Comment: This answer is a bit irrelevant. The **Authentication** and **Obfuscation** have been removed from the example. I am looking for an exact replica of the example but using a json file as a **db**.

Comment: @ZombieChowder  So you want the result be same with http://plnkr.co/edit/H4SVl6?p=preview right? Keep all the features?

Comment: yes but instead of using `username === 'test' && password === 'test'` to store the password, having a json file in which I could insert more usernames and passwords..

Comment: @ZombieChowder OK I see.

Comment: @ZombieChowder  You want to insert more usernames and passwords by editing the json file by hand, right? Since you don't actually have a server.

Comment: yes, that was the entire concept of the question and I why I have a bounty for it. Otherwise it would be just following the example.

Comment: @ZombieChowder  How about this one? http://plnkr.co/edit/WvOwk1?p=preview  I changed the "services.js". Check data.json to find available users.

Comment: If that's what you want, I'll update it to my answer.

Comment: yes, update your answer. This is what I am looking for. It would be nice if you could explain how you fixed it exactly.

Comment: @ZombieChowder fine

Comment: it will allow me to give you the bounty in 18 hours.

Answer (score 1):

check this example:

```
.controller('NameOfYourController', function($scope, $http,  $timeout) {
    $scope.details = ""; // you can even omit the declaration here 
    $http.get("data.json").then(function(response){
        $scope.details = response.data;
        console.log($scope.details.username); // or response.data.username   
        $timeout(function () {
          // you get to the response obj using: response.data.your_object
          // $timeout logic goes here
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**note: if you are inside a service you do not have a $scope**

Comment: thank you for your effort Paolo. This is declared within a factory and when I move it to the controller the entire thing breaks. As I've said, I am working on this example, check it out if you need additional information [Example](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/angularjs-basic-http-authentication-example). Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why `$scope` is undefined from your example. You're most likely not injecting it like you are with `$http` or `$timeout`. Another possibility is that you are trying to use `$scope` in something other than a controller.

As for your second error, `details` is undefined since it is set after the `.then()` promise is resolved. You would want to move your `$timeout` logic into that block of code like this:

```
var details;
$http.get("data.json").then(function(response){
    $scope.details = response.data;
    // ADD YOUR $timeout LOGIC HERE SO DETAILS IS NOT UNDEFINED
});
```

Comment: `[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20AuthenticationService` This is the error message I get whenever I insert the $scope in the controller. I have already tried that. That's why I left a link to the actual example.

Comment: This error shows me that you're injecting `$scope` into a Service. You cannot do that in AngularJS. Try moving the logic to a Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example , are You trying to put function for reading json file in Service method. If you are doing it then there is no $scope available in service. Hence you are getting below error

```
ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
```

In your code , there is local variable **details** is defined but not initialized. hence its value is undefined.

```
  var details;
```

and in timeout function you are trying to access **details.username**

```
username === details.username
```

hence you are getting below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

But if you want to do it most easiest way then just put your code in controller like below in [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/H4SVl6?p=preview) plunker. you should have creates data.json file to run below code.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Authentication')

.controller('LoginController',
    ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService','$http','$timeout',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService,$http,$timeout) {
        // reset login status
        AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
         var details;
        $http.get("data.json").then(function(response){
        $scope.details = response.data;
        //alert($scope.details.username);
        });

       function Login(username,password,callback){
            $timeout(function(){
                var response = { success: username === $scope.details.username && password === $scope.details.password };
                if(!response.success) {
                    response.message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
                }
                callback(response);
            }, 1000);
       }

        $scope.login = function () {
            $scope.dataLoading = true;
            Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response) {
                if(response.success) {
                    AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                    $location.path('/');
                } else {
                    $scope.error = response.message;
                    $scope.dataLoading = false;
                }
            });
        };
    }]);
```

But if you want to go with same controller and make changes in service then find answer by **@blackmiaool** which is absolutely perfect.

> What is the esiest way to achieve what I am trying to do? Extract the
>   username and password from a json file and not have them as a static
>   string?

The first approach is most easiest approach but it is not a standard practice.

The second approach is correct and standard approach for what you are trying to do.

Comment: this example makes sense but it doesn't work. The application freezes after the login button is clicked.

Comment: there must be some error while you are trying. I was also getting same error . Please work on it in plunker . i am able to run it in plunker.

Comment: Please find this plunker link of this example. http://plnkr.co/edit/RMYguZGwHvVKmA6oXJ5F?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Observations based on the below errors **:**

**1. ReferenceError: $scope is not defined**

- This error comes when we are trying to access the $scope object but forgot to inject as a dependency into the controller.

  ```
  app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { ... }
  ```

**2. TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined**

- What is `username` in your code ?
- You should use `$scope.details.username` instead of only `username`.

**Your code should be formatted like this :**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('LoginController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var details;
    $http.get("data.json").then(function(response){
        $scope.details = response.data;
        console.log($scope.details.username);
    });

    $timeout(function () {
        var response = { success: username === $scope.details.username && password === $scope.details.password 
        if (!response.success) {
            response.message = 'Username or password is incorrect';
        }
        callback(response);
    }, 1000);        
}]);
```